# Filling Online Form - Values not saving

Tags: html, vba, excel, textarea

Good morning,

I have created a basic VBA program in Excel that auto fills an online form by using: `IE.Document.getElementById(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")`

This works fine, when the online form is using textareas (i.e. under inspect element I see):

`<div class = "fields-container">
   <div class = "name long-field">
      <textarea id = "random-name" placeholder= "randomstuff" style="height: 24px;: ></textarea>`

However, not all the boxes on this form are textareas. Some boxes that I need to fill in looks like this under inspect element:

`<label class="has-float-label shadow" for="random-name"> == $0
   <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <input value id="random-name" style="box-sizing: content-box; 2px;">`

Whenever I try using the same `IE.Document.getElementById(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")` , it may fill out a letter or two, but then when I click in any other box on the form, the couple letters it inputed will delete.

When looking through the inspect element, it appears that even when those couple letters are filled in, it shows the Value as blank. I've tried putting "TEST" in the online form, then using the program to replace it, and although it shows it as replaced (well a couple letters at least), under inspect element the Value is still "TEST".

I hope there is an easy solution to this, but any help will be very appreciated. Please let me know if you need to see anymore of the code or InspectElement

*UPDATE* I tried using`.setAtrribute("value","RandomText")` and now under inspect element it shows the value as the "RandomText", however it doesn't change what's actually in the box, and when the page is refreshed, it reverts to whatever was in the box previously

I've also tested changing the Value by hand (under Inspect Element), and the textbox will change, but then when clicked on, will revert to whatever it had in it before

*UPDATE2* Here's some of the code from Inspect Element

`<input id="randomID" style="width:40px; box-sizing: content-box;" value="ProgramValue" />`

`<div style="left 0px; top 0px; text-transform:none; letter-spacing: normal; overflow: scroll; font-family: -apple-systm, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; white-space: pre; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">TEST</div>`

As you can see the actual Value is what the vba program is putting in, however at the end of style it still has the "TEST" text (and that is what's showing up on the actual web page). Is there a way to change that text?

(If you happen to have SIPR access let me know, and I can set you the site and more details)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after some research I came with the following solution:

```html
Set itemName = ieDoc.getElementById("dynamicLineItems").getElementsByClassName("InputBox")(0)
    itemName.Focus
    itemName.FireEvent ("onchange")
    itemName.Value = somevalue.Value
```

What I added to make it work is the .FireEvent("onchange") after using Inspect Element (with IE) on the input boxes I was working with (see image attached).
[IE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YZaV.jpg)

Maybe you can try modify your code with the events realted to your HTML forms